# Windows UWP Sensor API: Compass Heading vs Display Orientation

Tags: windows, uwp, orientation, display, compass

In Windows Mobile devices (tablet and phone), the programmer must consider the device or the display orientation respectively to treat the compass heading correctly.
In Microsofts UWP documentation there is a table with the compass heading in dependence of the display orientation as follows:

[image: Compass Heading in Dependence of the Display Orientation]

However, I think this table shows only the values for landscape-first devices like tablets.

When I use my windows 8.1 phone, however, it runs still under Windows Mobile 8.1 as OS, and do some tests, I get:

[image: Compass Heading in Dependence of the Display Orientation for Windows Phone 8.1]

Thus it seems, there is any difference in using landscape-first vs portrait-first devices. The first ones have compass heading 0, when facing in landscape mode to north, the latter ones have compass heading 0, when facing in portrait mode to north.

However, I used a Windows 8.1 device to do my tests. In Microsofts UWP documentation there is no difference mentioned between the two types of devices converning the compass heading.

So my question is:

Does the Windows UWP API treat the compass heading in another way than in older Windows devices ?

Or, do I have to distinguish between landscape-first and portrait-first devices in Windows UWP app, when I use compass heading and I wand to consider the display orientation to show the correct compass direction ?